# Why my log_civicrm_setting is keep growing with random entries?

Tags: logs, logging

I have noticed this since upgraded to 5.36.x that my log_civicrm_setting is kept growing in size with some random navigation enties. No idea what it is. Cannot find these in the civicrm_setting either.

Has anyone experienced this? How did you fix it.

[image]

Comment: Looks like you have caching enabled, (check under debbuging and backtrace)

Comment: Thanks @PradeepNayak but my asset caching is disabled in the settings.

Comment: Has anyone figured this one out? Not sure why the navigation items would keep getting logged. It was creating slow queries, impacting our server performance so I ended up truncating the entire table (after backing it up just in case there was something of interest). 3 hours later, there are 7K new entries, almost all of them "navigation" ... I'm positive we haven't made any changes to the navigation settings so not sure why they'd be getting logged : ( Thanks for any pointers.